# User activity (ala facebook) DB approach. Big JOIN or multiple simple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, android-activity

I need to display the users last activity in the website.
Reviews posted, images/video uploaded, voted articles and so on...

I have two tables:

'**user_activity**' table with 'userID', 'datetime', 'activityID' and 'externalID' columns.

'**activities**' table with 'activityID' and 'activity'.

Lets say that 'activityID' = 4, then I know that it reefers to an uploaded video (by looking at the 'activities' table) then I also know that externalID reefers to the 'videoID' from a third table called 'videos'.

The same for each type of activity, if its a review then 'externalID' reefers to 'reviewID' in the 'reviews' table.

When showing the user activity I don't want only to say the user uploaded an image but also show the uploaded image or video or whatever.

So,

When querying for the user last activity I can get the data by two ways:

1) Get the data from 'user_activity' table and then, make another query for each row to the external table (reviews, videos, images...) depending on the 'activityID'.

2) Make a big LEFT OUTER JOIN of all the tables (user_activity, reviews, videos, images...) together and then use only the relevant column based on 'activityID'.

So way 1 will cause a LOT of DB queries because I need a different query for each activity row. And way 2 will result in a BIG JOIN.

Any good advice on PROS CONS and with method is better??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have setup is called a polymorphic association. This is a problem that has been solved over and over again in different ways. You can find a lot of information out on the interwebz about this now that you know how to find it.

To answer your question more specifically: it depends. JOINs can be easier on the database if you setup the tables to use InnoDB and you only join on foreign keys. Unfortunately, InnoDB doesn't support polymorphic foreign keys.

Generally speaking, it's harder to scale the database than to scale your application, so anything you can do to move work from the DB layer into the application layer is a good thing. However, that's really only true of you're worried about scaling (and remember, premature optimization can be a death-blow to a startup).

Check out the top answers to this question on Quora for some more detailed information: [What are the scaling issues to keep in mind while developing a social network feed?](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-scaling-issues-to-keep-in-mind-while-developing-a-social-network-feed?q=scaling+social+network)

Answer (score 2):

None.

The solution for high traffic sites is [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) which means that you'll have some redundant data but your user activity query will be a very simply one, fetching all required data from a single table.

Comment: So you suggest to add a all the data I need to the 'user_activity' table? It will be a 20+ columns table. And what happens if the user updates/erase the content??

Comment: On updates you need to update this table with the redundant data. This is done either via application code or database triggers. Regarding the columns, whether you'll have 20+ columns or a summary of the update it's up to you. I'd transform all different kind of user updates (photos, comment, videos) into a unique entity (activity update) which would hold the data just for presentation in the activity feed.