# MySQL syntax clarification about FROM keyword

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I built the following query using [this MySQL doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) that I found through [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115057/limit-1-inside-join-from-specific-tables-in-mysql)

It gives me what I wanted: one record for each personkey, and the maximum (most recent) matchkey that that person has participated in.

but I don't understand the purpose of the "s1" and "s2," nor do I understand the construction used in the FROM line (and because I don't know what it's called, it's been difficult to search on it.)  What is actually going on in this query?

```
SELECT personforeignkey, matchforeignkey

FROM   peoplematchesheroes s1

WHERE  matchforeignkey = (SELECT MAX(s2.matchforeignkey)
                          FROM peoplematchesheroes s2
                          WHERE s1.personforeignkey = s2.personforeignkey)
```

Note: I understand that this query is inefficient, but I want to understand the correlated-subquery construction before I try to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s1 and s2 are *[table aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)*, in this case both for the same table 'peoplematchesheroes'. s1 is used as the alias for the outer query, and s2 for the inner correlated subquery.

It's not necessary to use a table alias for a correlated subquery, but in your case, since your inner query is also referring to the same table as the outer query, you need to alias them. Think of it as a resolution of scope, because otherwise it would be impossible to tell which 'personforeignkey' field you are referring to- the one from the table correlated subquery or from the outer one.

Hope this makes sense.